# How to rename folder even if this target folder has already exist?

Tags: java

How to rename folder even if the target folder with same name has already existed in the directory.

I have tried the method `renameTo` of class `File`,but it does not work.

For example:

> /root
>
> ```
> /a
> /b
> ```

I want to rename folder `b` with the name of folder `a`, actually the folder `a` will be replaced,yes,that's what I want.

Comment: Check if `/a` exists, if it does, recursively delete it, then move `/b` to `/a`.

Comment: Exeptions and code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first delete everything in 'a' or move/rename it to something else. 
You can delete it with Apache's recurrsive deleteDictionary function. This gets every file in the aFolder and deletes it, then deletes the folder itself.

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(aFolder);
```

Then, you can use #renameTo

```
bFolder.renameTo(aFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 and above you can turn to [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for `delete` and `move`.

In your case, you can achieve it as follows:

```
public class HelloWord {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Path targetPath = Paths.get(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().concat("/src/resources/").concat("a"));
        Path thePath = Paths.get(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().concat("/src/resources/").concat("b"));
        if (Files.exists(targetPath)) { // if the target folder exists, delete it first;
            deleteFolder(targetPath);
        }
        Files.move(thePath, targetPath);
    }

    private static void deleteFolder(Path path) {
        try {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) { // delete regular file directly;
                Files.delete(path);
                return ;
            }
            try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path)) {
                paths.filter(p -> p.compareTo(path) != 0).forEach(p -> deleteFolder(p)); // delete all the children folders or files;
                Files.delete(path); // delete the folder itself;
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

#### My local test

The structure of the folder for my local test is as follows:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution uses  `java.nio.file.Files` class's `move` static method.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class FilesMoveExample {
    public static void main (String [] args)
            throws IOException {
        Path srcePath = Paths.get("C:\\java-nio2\\folder1");        
        Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\java-nio2\\folder2");
        Files.move(srcePath, targetPath); // NOTE: Statement A
    }
}
```

Assume `folder1` is source directory and contains multiple sub-directories and files.

*Scenario 1:*
'Statement A' used as it is.
Source `folder1` exists and the target `folder2` does not exist.
On running the code, `folder1` is renamed to `folder2`. The `folder1`'s file tree is moved to `folder2`.

*Scenario 2:*
'Statement A' modified to: `Files.move(srcePath, targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`
Source `folder1` and the target `folder2` (an *empty* directory) exists.
On running the code, the target `folder2` is replaced with `folder1` (and renamed to `folder2`). The `folder1`'s file tree is moved to `folder2`.

*Scenario 3:*
'Statement A' modified to: `Files.move(srcePath, targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`
Source `folder1` and the target `folder2` (a *non-empty* directory) exists.
On running the code, throws `DirectoryNotEmptyException`.

In this scenario 3 the target directory needs to be empty for the move to complete successfully. So, delete the target directory recursively using one of the following methods, and perform the move. The first uses Java 7 and the next uses Java 8:

```
private static void deleteUsingWalkFileTree(Path start)
        throws IOException {        
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e)
                throws IOException {
            if (e == null) {
                Files.delete(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void deleteUsingWalk(Path start )
        throws IOException {
    List<Path> files = Files.walk(start)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Path p : files) {
        Files.delete(p);
    }
}
```